# $h(x)$ is $0$ if $x$ is an integer power of $2,$ and $1$ otherwise. $\lim_{x \to \infty} h(x) = ?$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$h(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x$ is an integer power of 2} \\
1, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} h(x) = ?$$

I have no idea how to approach this problem. Usually I would list out all of my steps and where exactly I am stuck, but this just doesn't make sense to me. It's not like $h(x)$ is an oscillating function like $\sin(x)$ so its limit should be defined, but as $h(x)$ approaches infinity, does it approach an integer power of $2?$ I don't know what to do.

Comment: What makes you say it's not oscillating? It might not have a fixed period, like a trig function, but...

Comment: In this situation you need to write down the definition of a limit and apply it. Chances are this question has been posed specifically to force you to proceed in this way.

Comment: Bernard, Can you be more specific? I looked up the Wikipedia definition for a limit and I wasn't sure what you meant. I haven't learned the definition with epsilon yet, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:
What is $h$ for $x=3^k$ where $k$ is any positive integer?

**Exercise**:  Show that the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}h(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: Oh is it I show that the limit as x goes to infinity means 3^k goes to infinity so h is 0, but as x goes to infinity so does if x = 2^k then 2^k also goes to infinity so h is 1, since they're not equal, DNE?

Comment: More or less yes. You might want to be careful about the writing though.